# jQuery carousel image slider (smooth fade-in/fadeout) autoscrolling not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, carousel

I have a script of image slider. All works but the slides switch too sharply and I can not add any smoothness that only I did not do, the result is zero. Also not working all effects on mobile/tablet devices. Please help upgrade the script. Thank you. Let the power be with you!

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<style>
.wbsn-animate-slider-opacity {animation:opacity-slider 2s;-ms-animation:opacity-slider 2s;-webkit-animation:opacity-slider 2s;-moz-animation:opacity-slider 2s;-o-animation:opacity-slider 2s;}
.wbsn-display-container{position:relative;}
.wbsn-content{max-width:980px;margin:auto;}
.wbsn-animate-bottom{position:relative;animation:animatebottom 0.4s;}
@keyframes animatebottom{from{bottom:-300px;opacity:0;} to{bottom:0;opacity:1;}}
@keyframes opacity-slider{from{opacity:0;} to{opacity:1;}}
</style>


<p></p><div class="wbsn-display-container wbsn-content wbsn-animate-bottom" style="background-color:#C48B48!important;box-shadow:0 0 3px #7B2F04;">
<img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/00.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;"><img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/01.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;">
<img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/02.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;"><img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/03.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;">
<img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/04.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;"><img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/05.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;">
<img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/06.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;"><img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/07.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;">
<img class="Slides" src="img/sliding/08.jpg" style="width:100%;border:0px;background-color:#C48B48!important;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var myIndex = 0; carousel();

function carousel() { var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Slides");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
   x[i].classList.remove("wbsn-animate-slider-opacity");
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
x[myIndex-1].classList.add("wbsn-animate-slider-opacity");
setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change every 5 sec
}</script>
```

My JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1mxz6nzw

Comment: Try it , https://jsfiddle.net/parlad/ke6Ld72s/

Comment: @parladneupane... Thank you... Sorry, but nothing change, as you can see... May be my question is wrong... I need that images fade-out very smooth like fade in in my example, but not so sharp as is... And i don't use bootstrap [data-wow-duration="5s"] in my example, just Jquery and JS))